# Limit touch space to half the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I limit the touch space to the right side of the screen so that it only registers the right side touches. Left side touch nothing will happen. How am I able to do it with this script? Been trying out for the past 2 days still cannot figure anything out. Any experts able to help me out?

```
public class look2 : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector3 firstpoint; //change type on Vector3
private Vector3 secondpoint;
private float xAngle = 0.0f; //angle for axes x for rotation
private float yAngle = 0.0f;
private float xAngTemp = 0.0f; //temp variable for angle
private float yAngTemp = 0.0f;
public GameObject character;
void Start()
  {
    //Initialization our angles of camera
    xAngle = 0.0f;
    yAngle = 0.0f;
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
    character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
}
void Update()
{
    //Check count touches
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        //Touch began, save position
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            firstpoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            xAngTemp = xAngle;
            yAngTemp = yAngle;
        }
        //Move finger by screen

            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                secondpoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                //Mainly, about rotate camera. For example, for Screen.width rotate on 180 degree
                xAngle = xAngTemp + (secondpoint.x - firstpoint.x) * 180.0f / Screen.width;
                yAngle = yAngTemp - (secondpoint.y - firstpoint.y) * 90.0f / Screen.height;
                //Rotate camera
                this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
            character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
          }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Screen.width`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html) to get exactly that: The width of the device's screen in pixels.

Since the [`Touch.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) is also in screen pixel space the right half of the screen is as simple as any touch having

```
touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2f
```

you could also use `>=` depending whether you want one pixel more or less ;)

And then you could simply filter the touches on that condition before accessing them e.g. using [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)

```
var validTouches = Input.touches.Where(touch => touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2f).ToArray();
```

This is basically short for doing something like

```
var touches = new List<Touch>();
foreach(var touch in Input.touches)
{
    if(touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2f)
    {
        touches.Add(touch);
    }
}
var validTouches = touches.ToArray();
```

So your code could look like

```
using System.Linq;

...

void Update()
{
    //Check count touches
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        // Now collect only touches being on the left half of the screen
        var validTouches = Input.touches.Where(touch => touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2f).ToArray();

        if(validTouches.Length > 0)
        {
            var firstTouch = validTouches[0];

            // Better use switch here
            switch(firstTouch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:   
                    firstpoint = firstTouch.position;
                    xAngTemp = xAngle;
                    yAngTemp = yAngle;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    secondpoint = firstTouch.position;
                    //Mainly, about rotate camera. For example, for Screen.width rotate on 180 degree
                    xAngle = xAngTemp + (secondpoint.x - firstpoint.x) * 180.0f / Screen.width;
                    yAngle = yAngTemp - (secondpoint.y - firstpoint.y) * 90.0f / Screen.height;
                    //Rotate camera
                    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
                    character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks it works! How stupid am I. Got a lot to learn from. Thank you buddy :)

Comment: @Dr.Joben Oh just read again and ofcourse you want to invert the condition since you actually wanted the right side not the left ;)

Comment: Yeap I did :). Btw, by any chance would you know how to change the rotation speed of quaternion? So I can increase or decrease the look sensitivity. I tried multiply by sensitivity and delta time but it does not work.. if you didn't know it's fine. you already helped me alot :)